# Filtrar array de objetos pela chave

Tags: javascript, regex

No momento ele está retornando somente se a string a ser consultada for **exatamente** igual a chave do objeto

```js
let estilos = { "alignContent": [ { "ativo": false } ], "alignItems": [ { "ativo": false } ], "alignSelf": [ { "ativo": false } ], "alignmentBaseline": [ { "ativo": false } ], "all": [ { "ativo": false } ], "animation": [ { "ativo": false } ], "animationDelay": [ { "ativo": false } ], "animationDirection": [ { "ativo": false } ], "animationDuration": [ { "ativo": false } ], "animationFillMode": [ { "ativo": false } ], "animationIterationCount": [ { "ativo": false } ], "animationName": [ { "ativo": false } ], "animationPlayState": [ { "ativo": false } ], "animationTimingFunction": [ { "ativo": false } ], "backfaceVisibility": [ { "ativo": false } ], "background": [ { "ativo": false } ], "backgroundAttachment": [ { "ativo": false } ], "backgroundBlendMode": [ { "ativo": false } ] };

const allowed = 'alignContent';

const filtered = Object.keys(estilos)
  .filter(key => allowed.match(new RegExp(key, 'g')))
  .reduce((obj, key) => {
    obj[key] = estilos[key];
    return obj;
  }, {});
  
console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: Qual seria a pergunta?

Comment: Já solucionei, vou editar para ficar como referência

Comment: Posta uma resposta e edita a pergunta colocando qual era o problema que não foi colocado

Comment: colocar a solução na pergunta não é o correto... a pergunta é o problema, a solução deve ser uma resposta

Comment: Reverte essa última alteração e adiciona a resposta no campo de resposta. Depois é só marcar como resolvido. A pessoa que tiver uma dúvida semelhante, ao entrar aqui, vai ficar "perdida" sem saber como fazer também.

Comment: realmente, editado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`allowed` e `key` devem ter seus lugares invertidos, assim a consulta se da por cada letra, também é bom adicionar o método `toLowerCase` para que a pesquisa seja feita independente de maiúsculo ou minúsculo...

```js
let estilos = { "alignContent": [ { "ativo": false } ], "alignItems": [ { "ativo": false } ], "alignSelf": [ { "ativo": false } ], "alignmentBaseline": [ { "ativo": false } ], "all": [ { "ativo": false } ], "animation": [ { "ativo": false } ], "animationDelay": [ { "ativo": false } ], "animationDirection": [ { "ativo": false } ], "animationDuration": [ { "ativo": false } ], "animationFillMode": [ { "ativo": false } ], "animationIterationCount": [ { "ativo": false } ], "animationName": [ { "ativo": false } ], "animationPlayState": [ { "ativo": false } ], "animationTimingFunction": [ { "ativo": false } ], "backfaceVisibility": [ { "ativo": false } ], "background": [ { "ativo": false } ], "backgroundAttachment": [ { "ativo": false } ], "backgroundBlendMode": [ { "ativo": false } ] };

const allowed = 'align';

const filtered = Object.keys(estilos)
  .filter(key => key.match( new RegExp(allowed, 'gi')))
  .reduce((obj, key) => {
    obj[key] = estilos[key];
    return obj;
  }, {});
  
console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: Nem precisava usar toLowerCase()... já que tá usando regex faz mais sentido usar a flag "i". MAs se tá feliz assim, çuçeçu

Comment: cara eu tenho um sério problema com regex kkk, valeu